# boost::msm usage: how to set properties of target states

Tags: c++, boost

States in my fsm has different properties. I define a event which will invoke a transition to a target state. I want to set properties of target by event data. My choices are:
1. set properties in the action or guard: but it is still in the source state. I fill not good if i set the target state properties at the time
2. set properties in the target entry: but the value of properties have been calculated in guard on receiving the event so i should recalculated again :(

Any one can give me more ideas. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your situation but I think that you have two different issue. One is where is the best place to set the target state's property. The other is how to avoid re-calculation.

Let's consider the former issue. As you mentioned, there are two candidates. They are a transition action and a target state's entry action. I think both are OK. If you use the target state's entry action, you need to care about event type. If you write the handler as follows, all events are caught by the handler.

```
    template <class Event, class Fsm>
    void on_entry(Event const& e, Fsm&) {
        std::cout << "State2::on_entry()" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "You can also set the property here." << std::endl;
        property = e.data;
    }
```

You can specify the event as follows:

```
    template <class Fsm>
    void on_entry(Event1 const& e, Fsm&) {
        std::cout << "State2::on_entry()" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "You can also set the property here." << std::endl;
        property = e.data;
    }
```

To solve the latter issue, how to avoid re-calculation, you need to declare the member variable in the event as mutable as follows:

```
    struct Event1 {
        mutable int data; // mutable is required because Event is passed as const&.
    };
```

Because Boost.MSM passes the Event parameter as a const reference.

Here is a code that describes how to set the target state property without re-calculation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>

#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

// StateMachine [Sm]
//
// (initial)
//    |
//    V
// State1 --Event1[Guard1]/Action1--> State2
//

// ----- Events
struct Event1 {
    mutable int data; // mutable is required because Event is passed as const&.
};

struct Sm_:msmf::state_machine_def<Sm_>
{
    // States
    struct State1:msmf::state<>
    {
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) const {
            std::cout << "State1::on_entry()" << std::endl;
        }
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {
            std::cout << "State1::on_exit()" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct State2:msmf::state<>
    {
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_entry(Event const& e, Fsm&) {
            std::cout << "State2::on_entry()" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "You can also set the property here." << std::endl;
            property = e.data;
        }
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_exit(Event const&, Fsm&) const {
            std::cout << "State2::on_exit()" << std::endl;
        }
        int property;
    };
    // Set initial state
    typedef State1 initial_state;

    // Guards
    struct Guard1 {
        template <class Event, class Fsm, class Source, class Target>
        bool operator()(Event const& e, Fsm&, Source&, Target&) const {
            e.data *= 2; // calc
            std::cout << "In Guard1, e.data *= 2. e.data=" << e.data << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    };

    // Actions
    struct Action1 {
        template <class Event, class Fsm, class Source, class Target>
        void operator()(Event const& e, Fsm&, Source&, Target& t) const {
            std::cout << "In Action1, set target state property based on event data that is calculated in Guard1." << std::endl;
            t.property = e.data;
        }
    };

    // Transition table
    struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        //          Start   Event   Next    Action      Guard
        msmf::Row < State1, Event1, State2, Action1,    Guard1 >
    > {};
};

// Pick a back-end
typedef msm::back::state_machine<Sm_> Sm;

void test()
{
    Sm sm;
    sm.start();

    std::cout << "> Send Event1()" << std::endl;
    Event1 e1;
    e1.data = 12;
    sm.process_event(e1);
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

You can compile, run, and modify the code using Wandbox, online compiler.
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L1HAjIiLU091906u

Comment: Takatoshi, your code solves my problem. thanks a lot.